# Ionic Cordova iOS app failed to build "Command failed with exit code 65: xcodebuild"

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, admob

I am currently building an app with ionic cordova for iOS. normally everything is fine but when I try to run, "ionic cordova build iOS" the project fails. I dont know what todo since this is a new error.

Command Line Result:

```
The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/trevormarr/Documents/Offroadin/Repository/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/offroadin-app.app/offroadin-app normal (in target 'offroadin-app' from project 'offroadin-app')
(1 failure)
Command failed with exit code 65: xcodebuild -workspace offroadin-app.xcworkspace -scheme offroadin-app -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -destination platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 14 Pro Max build SYMROOT=/Users/trevormarr/Documents/Offroadin/Repository/platforms/ios/build
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

I tried to build my app for iOS using the build command but its seems to have an issue with some simulator thing. ive updated my Xcode and simulators but it still doesn't work.

The only new feature ive added was the AdMob plugin and all those SDKs from the cordova community plugins. Thats the only thing I can think of is causing the issue.

Comment: Error code 65 is one of the most generic error codes iOS has. There is probably a more specific error message higher up in the log (although iOS logs are a mess, so it might be a bit hard to find)